# Why do the worms produce spice, and what ecological role does it play?

Tags: dune

In the novel, Liet Kynes tells Leto and Paul that the worms defend the spice. From this, Paul infers a likely relationship which turns out to be correct. The worms make it. But why do they do so? Is it part of their reproductive cycle? Do other desert creatures feed on it?

Why do the worms produce spice, and what role does it play in the ecology of Arrakis?

As an aside, it seems odd how little curiosity there is in universe about this extremely valuable limited resource. One would think there would be teams of planetary ecologists trying to find out everything they could!

Comment: Have you read the first appendix at the end of the novel, titled "The ecology of Dune"?

Comment: A very long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

They do not merely "create" the spice, they are the spice.  Consider the water of life, which is very distilled in its impact to the Kwisatz Haderach, and is 100% comprised of sandtworm larvae and water.

Leto became a hybrid, integrating his human metabolism with their non-human one.  Given the extension of life by ~3400 years, the metabolic relationship was not parasitic, like leeches, so less mouth-to-excrete connection and more blood-to-blood.

https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Sandtrout
https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Spice_Melange
https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Leto_Atreides_II

Comment: This is a bit like saying that chickens are made of eggs.

Comment: More like chicken blood comes from chickens.

Comment: Spice is a rather complex chemical mixture.  While it may be poetic (at best) to say worms=spice in reality (albeit fictional) the trout excretions need to grow a fungus and react with sunlight and air.  https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Pre-spice_mass

Comment: worms != spice. +1 to Valorum's comment. Also - better than links to fan wiki would be quotes from the book proving your idea

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Was Leto a 3-way symbiosis between sandtrout, human, and fungus? How could the spice-content of the water of death/life give paul a prescient breakthrough and make him kwisatz haderach if it had no spice?  Its a weaker evidence, but not entirely without merit to ask how the Tleilax could hope to exfiltrate sandworms from Arrakis to break the spice monopoly without the fungus? Another weak evidence: fungus doesn't do well in high heat and bright light, but tends to need dark, cool, and moist to grow.

Comment: Water of life aka worm bile is no doubt chemically related to the sand trout excretion by product.  But in this case Bene Gesserit control of body chemistry is doing some chemistry.  It would be a good question if Chapterhouse made a documented special effort to include associated microbiomes associated with the worms and spice cycle.